# Changing the design of the first page of a new chapter

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, chapters

I have a chapter located in the back-matter part of a book-class document which I want to change the style for.

More precisely, I do not want to have the same big amount of space empty before the title and the text of the chapter start.

It is a *chapter* with no name and marked with an asterisk so that it doesn't appear in the list of contents, I mean, something like `chapter*{}`.

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[13pt]{book}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Intro and end}

Nothing to say here.

\backmatter

\chapter{This is a backmatter chapter}

\chapter*{}

\thispagestyle{empty} % I also want pages without page number and so on.

I would like this text to appear at the top of the page, as if it was the second or third page in a chapter.

I do want this to be a different chapter from the previous one.

Any help will be appreciated.

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
---like this text does, actually.

\end{document}
```

I guess this one is easy for many people here, but I am not used to deal with `\renewcommand` and `\setlenght` sentences...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure that I understand what you want. The main thing that is do not understand is why you are using `\chapter*` if you don't want a chapter. Why not just use `\newpage`, for example?

The second thing that I am unsure of is whether you would just to know how to redefine all instances of `\chapter*`, so that it never leaves such a large gap, or whether you want a new command that will do something similar.

I am going to assume that you just want to redefine `\chapter*`. If you want something else please rephrase your question or clarify in the comments below.

Looking in `book.cls` the `\chapter*` command ends up calling `\@schapter` and, in turn, this calls the command `\@makeschapterhead`. It is this last command that creates the extra space that you do not like, so if you redefine it then the space will disappear. This is done below with the result your errant page becomes

[image]

To do this you can simply copy the definition of `\@makeschapterhead` from `book.cls` and comment out the first line with `\vspace`. Here is modified version of your MWE (but see comments below as well):

```
\documentclass[13pt]{book}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{showframe}

\makeatletter% you need this because the commands below contain @'s 
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  %\vspace*{50\p@}% have just commented out this line
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Intro and end}

Nothing to say here.

\backmatter

\chapter{This is a backmatter chapter}

\chapter*{}

\thispagestyle{empty} % I also want pages without page number and so on.

I would like this text to appear at the top of the page, as if it was the second or third page in a chapter.

I do want this to be a different chapter from the previous one.

Any help will be appreciated.

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
---like this text does, actually.

\end{document}
```

Even though the hack above "fixes" your MWE it may not be enough for what you want because if you use `\chapter*{A title}` then still get some large gaps:

[image]

The reason for this is the `\vskip 40\p@` at the end of the `\@makeschapterhead` macro. If you need to use `\chapter*` with non-empty titles then you will need to adjust this 40pt vskip.

Finally, if you don't want to universally modify `\chapter*` please explain more clearly what you are looking for and I will modify this.

Comment: Perhaps one should use a `\patchcmd` that changes the spacing `\vskip 40\p@` to something that's more in the control of the user, say `\newlength{schapterafterskip}` and set it to, say, `20pt` etc.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Perhaps...I should learn what `\patchcmd` does and how to use it:)

Comment: `\patchcmd` changes the definition of code `\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vskip 40\p@}{\vskip \schafterafterskip}{}{}` should work, provided `\schapterafterskip` is defined. The `{}{}` can contain code for successful (1st) and failing (2nd) patching, but I let them empty, since I am lazy ;-)